# Saving a list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

All,

I am trying to save a list of objects in my model and when I step through it, execution lands on

```
db.Entry(model.Sponsors).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

and then gets caught:

*The entity type List`1 is not part of the model for the current context.*

The list is declared in the view model and the data is being pulled into the view OK. It's when I go to save the data that this occurs. How can I fix?

**The view that contains the form**

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Sponsors.Count; i++)
         {
             string sponsorDivId = "sponsorclubname" + i.ToString();
             string deleteLink = "<a class=\"icon delete cosponsor\" data-attr-divid=\""+@sponsorDivId+"\" data-attr-id=" + @Model.Sponsors[i].Id + "></a>";

             <div id="@sponsorDivId">
                 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Sponsors[i].Id)
                 <div class="formColumn1"><label for="sponsorclubname1">Sponsor club name</label></div>
                 <div class="formColumn2">@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Sponsors[i].SponsorContactName) 
                     <div class="messageBottom"> 
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sponsors[i].SponsorContactName)
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="formColumn3">@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Sponsors[i].SponsorContactEmail)
                     <div class="messageBottom"> 
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sponsors[i].SponsorContactEmail)
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="formColumn4">@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Sponsors[i].SponsorContactPhone)@(i > 0 ? Html.Raw(deleteLink) : Html.Raw(""))
                     <div class="messageBottom"> 
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sponsors[i].SponsorContactPhone)
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clear"></div>

         }
```

**The declaration of the list in the view model**

```
public List<NewClubSponsor> Sponsors { get; set; }
```

**The controller that does the processing**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessFormANewClubTeam(FormANewClubTeamViewModel model)
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        { 
            db.Entry(model.Sponsors).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


            {
                var err = "Error: " + ex.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Error: "+ err);
            }

        }
     }
    [...]
 }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it's saying is that `List<NewClubSponsor>` isn't a model that was generated by your database or your codefirst.

What you really want to do is save individual `NewClubSponsor` so you need to change each of those object's state. You also only want to change the object state for existing objects. You want to add new ones.

```
foreach(var sponser in model.Sponsors)
{
      if(sponser.ID <= 0)
      {
         db.Sponsors.Add(sponser);
      }
      else if(db.Entry(sponser).State == EntityState.Detached)
      {
         db.Sponsors.Attach(sponser);
         db.Entry(sponser).State = EntityState.Modified;
      }

}
db.SaveChanges();
```